# How to set date and integer value for my UI in sqlite?

Tags: ios, sqlite

I was set text and image its working fine but how to set date and integer values for my UI.
How to set date and integer value for my UI in sqlite iPhone? This is my comments class.h

```
    @interface Comments : NSObject
{
    NSInteger iD;
    UIImage *photo;
    NSString *name;
    NSString *descrp;
    NSDate *date;
    NSString *msg;
    NSInteger noofcomm;
    NSInteger nooflikes;
}
@property(nonatomic,assign)NSInteger iD;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UIImage *photo;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *name;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *descrp;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSDate *date;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *msg;
@property(nonatomic,assign)NSInteger noofcomm;
@property(nonatomic,assign)NSInteger nooflikes;
@end
```

And this is my RootViewController.h

```
    @interface RootViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *list;

}
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *list;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView *image2;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel *name2;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel *descrp2;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel *date2;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UITextView *msg2;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel *comments2;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel *likes2;
@end
```

This is my RootViewController.m

```
    #import "RootViewController.h"
#import "Comments.h"
#import "DBClass.h"

@interface RootViewController ()

@end

@implementation RootViewController
@synthesize list;
@synthesize image2;
@synthesize name2;
@synthesize descrp2;
@synthesize msg2;
@synthesize date2;
@synthesize comments2;
@synthesize likes2;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    DBClass * mywines =[[DBClass alloc] init];
    self.list = [mywines getMyComments];
    [self.image2 setImage:((Comments *) [self.list objectAtIndex:0]).photo];
    [self.name2 setText:((Comments *) [self.list objectAtIndex:0]).name];

    [self.descrp2 setText:((Comments *) [self.list objectAtIndex:0]).descrp];
    //[self.date2 setDate:((Comments *) [self.list objectAtIndex:0]).date];
    [self.msg2 setText:((Comments *) [self.list objectAtIndex:0]).msg];
      // [self.comments2 setText:((Comments *) [self.list objectAtIndex:0]).noofcomm];
  //  [self.likes2 setText:((Comments *) [self.list objectAtIndex:0]).nooflikes];


    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setImage2:nil];
    [self setName2:nil];
    [self setMsg2:nil];
    [self setDescrp2:nil];
    [self setComments2:nil];
    [self setLikes2:nil];
    [self setDate2:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at using `NSDateFormatter` to convert the date into a string and `stringWithFormat:` to convert the integer into a string. Then you can set the strings as the text of the labels.

Take a look at [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html) to learn more about date formatters and associated complexities.

---

```
NSString *numberText = [NSString stringWithFormat:(@"%d", integerValue];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSString *dateText = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateValue];
```

Comment: Please See my code once And It getting error undeclared identifier integerValue and dateValue

Comment: My code is an example of what to do, you need to look at it, understand it and then apply it to your problem.

Comment: Am retrieving from sqlite database and that value is set to label ,how to do that?

Comment: int solution = 1;
    [self.comments2 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", solution]]; Instead of int solution=1 I want to retrieve from sqlite database how to do that?

Comment: The use of SQLite is completely separate to your question. You need a new question for that.

Comment: I was set Image and text with sqlite see above code but how to set integer and date please how to do that explain me

Comment: Please add an update to your question showing how you have tried to use my example code.

Comment: I was asked new question please once see